# How to add a class to a link in functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some php which has some links within it which I'd like to style and turn into buttons.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'wpso_custom_links_admin_menu');
function wpso_custom_links_admin_menu() {
    global $submenu;
    $submenu['index.php'][] = array( 'Link One', 'read', 'https://www.example.com/' );
    $submenu['index.php'][] = array( 'Link Two', 'read', 'https://asdf.com/' );
}
```

The issue is that I'm not sure how or where to add a class here in order to style with css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'wpso_custom_links_admin_menu');
function wpso_custom_links_admin_menu() {
    global $submenu;
    $submenu['index.php'][] = array( 'Link One', 'read', 'https://www.example.com/', '', 'my-class');
    $submenu['index.php'][] = array( 'Link Two', 'read', 'https://asdf.com/', '', 'my-class');
}
```

Comment: OK. So tried it and then used the class I added in my css. For example `. jobs-dashboard {background-color: green;}` didn't work. Am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: Can you inspect element in admin panel and check if class is there?

Comment: I see that you have another question for making that css work. If class is added to html, then job for this question is done

Comment: Ok. Now remove space from `.jobs-dashboard` or `.jobs-dashboard1` in css. It goes without space between a dot and class name

Comment: That's just a Stack Overflow responsive issue. In the pre-publish page the space doesn't exist